# WinSCP successfully uploads to a CIFS automount but fails on the final rename

Tags: linux, redhat, winscp

One system has CIFS autofs home directories. I can upload files without issue but it seems to be failing on the final rename:

[image]

But I can see the file uploaded, just with the `.filepart` extension:

[image]

The final file is intact, the only thing that seems to be failing is the rename operation. I don't know why that would be the case. I've already tried to do `directio` on the directory and this isn't reproducible on NFS automounts on the same server. I have seen [this](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/message_transfer_finished_could_not_rename) and Symantec AV is running but this isn't happening on NFS and even with AV disabled I still get the error.

I'm kind of at a loss as to what to check

**EDIT:**

Added wrinkle, the error does *not* appear if the file is small (such as 9KB). It's only large files that have this issue.

Comment: *"the error does not appear if the file is small (such as 9KB)"* - Because WinSCP uses transfer to a temporary file name for files over 100 KB only (by default).